# Moving verticle lines around in a Matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, draggable, interactive, movable

I have been looking around for a while and cant seem to find much on moving elements around after they have been plotted. I have a series of vertical lines plotted and if they are to close together i would like to be able to space then out a bit more. The issue is that they cant be moved to the left ever. I have code that can evenly space all these with that constraint but now I0m focusing on just making sure they are not clumped together. here is an example picture of what I'm working with:

[full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD4qK.png)

[zoomed in on a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tCI6.png)

Thee question really is if there is a way I am able to click and drag these red lines around so they are not to close to others? i need to be able to retrieve the new positions of all the lines after this is done after i have made them all nicely spaced but i assume this would be fairly simple after i have this mechanic in place?

I'm not looking for specific implementation just some help on places I could look to be able to make this click and drag utility possible.

This may not be possible in matplotlib itself and i may have to look outward into making some GUI to do this but i have no experience in this so probably not the best solution although probably the best.

Any insight into how I might be able to achieve the click drag utility will be greatly appreciated!

-Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

got it working from a movable polygon example here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist




global new_freqs



def dist(x, y):
    """
    Return the distance between two points.
    """
    d = x - y
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(d, d))


def dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1):
    """
    Get the distance of a point to a segment.
      *p*, *s0*, *s1* are *xy* sequences
    This algorithm from
    http://www.geomalgorithms.com/algorithms.html
    """
    v = s1 - s0
    w = p - s0
    c1 = np.dot(w, v)
    if c1 <= 0:
        return dist(p, s0)
    c2 = np.dot(v, v)
    if c2 <= c1:
        return dist(p, s1)
    b = c1 / c2
    pb = s0 + b * v
    return dist(p, pb)


class PolygonInteractor:
    """
    A polygon editor.

    Key-bindings

      't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
          you can move them, delete them

      'd' delete the vertex under point

      'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
          line connecting two existing vertices

    """

    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, ax, poly, start_freqs):
        if poly.figure is None:
            raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure '
                               'or canvas before defining the interactor')
        self.ax = ax
        canvas = poly.figure.canvas
        self.poly = poly

        x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
        self.line = Line2D(x, y,
                           marker='o', markerfacecolor='r',
                           animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        
        ax.vlines(x,linestyle="--", ymin=0.0, ymax=1, alpha=0.9, color=col, gid="new_lines")
        
        self.original_freqs = start_freqs #variable for storing the starting frequencies
        self.orig_cols = col # array or starting colours
        self.new_cols = self.orig_cols # array or new colours, same as original to begin with
        self.issue_spacing = 1.0e6 # variable to store the value of kids to close together
        
        self.cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
        self._ind = None  # the active vert

        canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.on_draw)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_button_release)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_mouse_move)
        self.canvas = canvas
        
    
 
    def draw_new_positions(self):
        
        for i in range(len(self.new_cols)):
            if self.poly.xy[i,0] != self.original_freqs[i]:
                
                if self.poly.xy[i,0] < self.original_freqs[i]:
                    self.new_cols[i] = "purple"         #if the kid has moved backwward show purple
                elif (self.poly.xy[i+1,0]-self.poly.xy[i,0]) < self.issue_spacing or (self.poly.xy[i,0]-self.poly.xy[i-1,0]) < self.issue_spacing :
                    self.new_cols[i] = "black"         #if the kid to close the the ones next to it show black
                else:
                    self.new_cols[i] = "orange"         #if the kid has moved and is positioned ok show orange
            else:
                self.new_cols[i] = self.orig_cols[i]
        
        new_lines = self.ax.vlines(self.poly.xy[:-1,0], ymin=-1, ymax=0, linestyle="--", color=self.new_cols, alpha=0.9, gid="new_lines") #new line to move where mouse is
        self.ax.draw_artist(new_lines) # drawing the line on moving the mouse
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox) # blitting the canvas to render moving
        new_lines.remove()



    def on_draw(self, event):
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        # do not need to blit here, this will fire before the screen is
        # updated

    def poly_changed(self, poly):
        """This method is called whenever the pathpatch object is called."""
        # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
        vis = self.line.get_visible()
        Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
        self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state

    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        """
        Return the index of the point closest to the event position or *None*
        if no point is within ``self.epsilon`` to the event position.
        """
        # display coords
        xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
        xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        d = np.hypot(xt - event.x, yt - event.y)
        indseq, = np.nonzero(d == d.min())
        ind = indseq[0]

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button presses."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button releases."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None
        

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        """Callback for key presses."""
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        if event.key == 't':                 #toggles the movable points on and off
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            
            if not self.showverts:
                self._ind = None
        elif event.key == ' ':              #prints the x vals of all polygon points (which are the new frequencies) to the console
            
            new_freqs = self.poly.xy[:,0]
            for i in range(len(new_freqs)-1):
                print("{:.1f},".format(new_freqs[i])) 
            # print(len(new_freqs))
        
        elif event.key == 'l':        #save new frequencies to csv file and show final plot
            
            new_freqs = self.poly.xy[:-1,0]
            
            new_data = 0 
            
            
            new_data = np.zeros((len(new_freqs), 2))

            new_data[:,0] = data["kid_id"]
            new_data[:,1] = new_freqs
            
            
            new_data_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns=["kid_id", "f0"]) #makes a new data frame to save to csv with all new positions
            
            new_data_df.to_csv("new_kid_positions.csv", index=False)
            
            plt.close()
            
            plt.figure("new array", dpi=150)
            
            for i in range(len(new_data_df["f0"])):
                
                    if self.poly.xy[i,0] == self.original_freqs[i]:
                        col="green"
                    else:
                        col="orange"
                    
                    plt.axvline(new_data_df["f0"][i]/1e6, color=col, linestyle="--", linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.9)
                
            plt.plot([],[], color="orange", label="Moved")
            plt.plot([],[], color="green", label="Not moved")
                
            plt.legend(loc="best")
            plt.xlabel("Frequency     (MHz)")
            plt.ylabel("")
            plt.title("Altered array")
            plt.grid()
            plt.show()
            

        if self.line.stale:
            self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse movements."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            self.moving_line.remove()
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, 0

        self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x, y
        if self._ind == 0:
            self.poly.xy[-1] = x, y
        elif self._ind == len(self.poly.xy) - 1:
            self.poly.xy[0] = x, y
        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
        
        
        # self.remove_series()
        
        # f = x
        # self.add_series(f, "new_lines", len(self.poly.xy[:,0])-1)
        
        # ax.axvline(x, ymin=-1, ymax=1, linestyle="--", color="orange", alpha=0.9, animated=True)

        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        
        # self.moving_line = self.ax.axvline(x, ymin=-1, ymax=1, linestyle="--", color="orange", alpha=0.9) #new line to move where mouse is
        # self.ax.draw_artist(self.moving_line) # drawing the line on moving the mouse
        # self.moving_line.remove()
        self.draw_new_positions()
        
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox) # blitting the canvas to render moving
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

    
    #reading in freequency positions
    data = pd.read_csv("sorted_kids.csv")
    
    #getting color for each line
    col = [] #empty list
    for i in range(len(data["issue"])):
        
        if data["issue"][i] == 1:
            col.append("red")
        else:
            col.append("green")
    # col = np.array(col)
    
    xs = data["f0"]
    ys = np.zeros_like(xs)
        

    poly = Polygon(np.column_stack([xs, ys]), animated=True)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=150, figsize=(12,6))
    ax.add_patch(poly)
    p = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly, xs)

    ax.set_title('Click a point to drag. spacebar=print freqs. T=toggle move. L=save and show final solution')
    
    ax.plot([],[], color="black", alpha=0.0, label=r"TOP: ORIGINAL ARRAY")
    ax.plot([],[], color="red", label="to close")
    ax.plot([],[], color="green", label="spacing ok")
    ax.plot([],[], color="black", alpha=0.0, label="\nBOT: ALTEERED ARRAY")
    ax.plot([],[], color="red", label="orig position & to close")
    ax.plot([],[], color="green", label="orig position & ok")
    ax.plot([],[], color="purple", label="moved backward!")
    ax.plot([],[], color="black", label="to close still")
    ax.plot([],[], color="orange", label="moved & ok")
    ax.legend(loc=1, fontsize=6)
    
    plt.xlabel("Frequency     (Hz)")
    
    ax.set_xlim((min(data["f0"])-10e6, max(data["f0"])+10e6))
    ax.set_ylim((-1.5, 1.5))
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
    
    ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    
    plt.show()
```